# filterMany for Play 2 returns all results

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Play 2.0.2 with ebean.

In `Info` class, I defined

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<MemberInfo> members;

private Date createdDate = new Date();
```

And `MemberInfo` has `memberId` field.

When I do

```
public static Finder<Long,Info> find 
        = new Finder<Long,Info>(Long.class, Info.class);

find.fetch("members")
    .where().filterMany("members").eq("memberId", memberId)
    .order().desc("createdDate")
    .findList();
```

It returns all `Info`, without checking `memberId` of `members`.

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`filterMany()` doesn't filter parent results by children's expressions (both has separate 'ranges').

As descriped [in its API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#filterMany%28java.lang.String%29) it will find **all** `Info` objects and filtered `members` for each.

There is also very similar topic on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ebean/k0cKsUI-_tg) where author of the question gives his own workaround for this.

Examine the difference between:

```
find.fetch("members")
    .where().filterMany("members").eq("memberId", 1L)
    .findList();
```

and

```
find.fetch("members")
    .where().eq("members.memberId", 1L)
    .findList();
```