# play framework 2 ManyToMany relationships

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two classes :

```
public class Tag {
@Id
public int id;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public static List<Article> articles;

public static Finder<Long, Tag> find = new Finder<Long, Tag>(Long.class, Tag.class);
}


public class Article {  
@Id
public int id;

@Constraints.Required
public String title;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public static List<Tag> tags;

public static Finder<Long, Article> find = new Finder<Long, Article>(Long.class,     Article.class);
```

I need function that gain article as parameter and give back list of tags, related to this article

Comment: there is a `}` missing at the end of the second class. Besides: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<Tag> findTagsByArticle(Article article) {
    return find.fetch("articles").where().eq("articles.id", article.id).findList();     
}
```

Check similar [question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703629/filtermany-for-play-2-returns-all-results/11704403#11704403)

filterMany() is described [in its API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#filterMany%28java.lang.String%29)